# Joomla, com_community component showing in places

Tags: php, joomla

first of all i'm sorry i couldn't come up with a more concrete title for my question, it's just that i don't usually work with Joomla and this problem got me a little confused. It's hard for me to diagnose the problem since I'm not the one that implemented this theme and from what i've heard this theme is ripped, so it might be just a bad rip. I'm listening to any ideas or leads you guys might have.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpHSE.jpg

I used Php-grep to try and figure out what COM_COMMUNITY_VIDEOS_HITS_COUNT_MANY is and where it's coming from, but it didn't help much.

- /home/x23ligas/public_html/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_community.ini [189] 
  COM_COMMUNITY_VIDEOS_HITS_COUNT_MANY="%1$s views"
- /home/x23ligas/public_html/components/com_community/templates/jf_social_js_2.8/videos.video.php [69] 
  echo JText::sprintf('COM_COMMUNITY_VIDEOS_HITS_COUNT_MANY', $video->getHits());
- /home/x23ligas/public_html/components/com_community/templates/jf_social_js_2.8/videos.list.php [101] 
  echo JText::sprintf('COM_COMMUNITY_VIDEOS_HITS_COUNT_MANY', $video->getHits());
- /home/x23ligas/public_html/components/com_community/templates/jf_social_js_2.8/activities.system.topvideos.php [30] 
  echo JText::sprintf('COM_COMMUNITY_VIDEOS_HITS_COUNT_MANY', $video->getHits());
- /home/x23ligas/public_html/components/com_community/templates/default/videos.video.php [69] 
  echo JText::sprintf('COM_COMMUNITY_VIDEOS_HITS_COUNT_MANY', $video->getHits());
- /home/x23ligas/public_html/components/com_community/templates/default/videos.list.php [101] 
  echo JText::sprintf('COM_COMMUNITY_VIDEOS_HITS_COUNT_MANY', $video->getHits());
- /home/x23ligas/public_html/components/com_community/templates/default/activities.system.topvideos.php [30] 
  echo JText::sprintf('COM_COMMUNITY_VIDEOS_HITS_COUNT_MANY', $video->getHits());
- /home/x23ligas/public_html/tmp/install_51f4e3fbeacae/jf_social_js_2.8/videos.video.php [69] 
  echo JText::sprintf('COM_COMMUNITY_VIDEOS_HITS_COUNT_MANY', $video->getHits());
- /home/x23ligas/public_html/tmp/install_51f4e3fbeacae/jf_social_js_2.8/videos.list.php [101] 
  echo JText::sprintf('COM_COMMUNITY_VIDEOS_HITS_COUNT_MANY', $video->getHits());
- /home/x23ligas/public_html/tmp/install_51f4e3fbeacae/jf_social_js_2.8/activities.system.topvideos.php [30] echo JText::sprintf('COM_COMMUNITY_VIDEOS_HITS_COUNT_MANY', $video->getHits());

In research I also found that 'com_community' is a component for the Joomla! content manager.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem. Basically, the extension has untranslated language strings. With Joomla, you can use the language file to define bits of text which makes life easier when adding translations for extensions, for example:

```
COM_COMPONENT_HELLO="Hello"
```

IN your case, string such as `COM_COMMUNITY_VIDEOS_HITS_COUNT_MANY` have no been defined and therefore appear as they do.